# Event onclick to change background image

Tags: jquery, html, css, click, mouseevent

I'm beginner and write some HTML code but what I need is when I click on div to change background image... How I can do that?

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
#kat1 {
    background-image:url(ikoniceKategorije/07.jpg);
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    float:left;
    }
#kat1:hover {
    background-image:url(ikoniceKategorije/07h.jpg);
    }

#kat2 {
    background-image:url(ikoniceKategorije/06.jpg);
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    float:left;
    }
#kat2:hover {
    background-image:url(ikoniceKategorije/06h.jpg);
    }

#kat3 {
    background-image:url(ikoniceKategorije/05.jpg);
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    float:left;
    }
#kat3:hover {
    background-image:url(ikoniceKategorije/05h.jpg);
    }

#kat4 {
    background-image:url(ikoniceKategorije/04.jpg);
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    float:left;
    }
#kat4:hover {
    background-image:url(ikoniceKategorije/04h.jpg);
    }
#kat5 {
    background-image:url(ikoniceKategorije/03.jpg);
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    float:left;
    }
#kat5:hover {
    background-image:url(ikoniceKategorije/03h.jpg);
    }

#kat6 {
    background-image:url(ikoniceKategorije/02.jpg);
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    float:left;
    }
#kat6:hover {
    background-image:url(ikoniceKategorije/02h.jpg);
    }

#kat7 {
    background-image:url(ikoniceKategorije/01.jpg);
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    float:left;
    }
#kat7:hover {
    background-image:url(ikoniceKategorije/01h.jpg);
    }
#div {
    width:220px;
    height:30px;
    overflow:hidden;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="div">
        <div id="kat1"></div>
        <div id="kat2"></div>
        <div id="kat3"></div>
        <div id="kat4"></div>
        <div id="kat5"></div>
        <div id="kat6"></div>
        <div id="kat7"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

or you can see at on www.pluspon.com/kategorije.html what I plan to do. Change Image on hover and on click also... THANKS !!!

Comment: or some other way how to do that... maybe jquery or javascript ???

Comment: You should use classes not ids. and change the class after click.

Comment: OK, but how to change class on click?

Comment: `$(selector)\$(this).addClass('foo').removeClass('bar');`

Comment: please write this in an answer more detailed. THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery you could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#kat1").click(function () {
        $(this).css("background-image", "xxx.png");
    });
});
```

If you wan´t to toggle you could do:

```
$("#kat1").click(function () {
    if ($(this).css("background-image") == first_Image) {
        $(this).css("background-image", second_Image);
    }
    else {
        $(this).css("background-image", first_Image);
    } 
});
```

});

Comment: Yes, but when I click two times then will stay the same image... I need to change image on click once and when I click second time to back original image... ( one image is balck$white and other is in color)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var img=["picture1.jpg","picture2.jpg","picture3.jpg","picture4.jpg"];
    var index =0;
  $('#kat1').on("click",function(){
       $('#kat1').css('background-image',img[index]);
        if(index==3){
            index=0;
        }else{
            index++;
        }           
   });
</script>
```

would change the background of your kat1 div. Now you would have 4 different images. What you could also do is take pictures of lorempixum.com This will always deliver different pictures.

Comment: Or you can use $('#kat1').addclass('altimage'); if you want to have the alternate images declared as classes in your CSS file.

Comment: Yes, but when I click two times then will stay the same image... I need to change image on click once and when I click second time to back original image... ( one image is balck$white and other is in color)

Comment: @Feysal what the hell are you talking about ? That is complete nonsene what you are talking about. .on() has nothing to do with tabindexes

Comment: Use toggle instead of click then you can define a second function to remove the css you added. `$('#kat1').toggle(function(){}, function(){});`

Comment: Sorry, confused with the way `focus` events are handled... those work on divs without `tabindex` only on IE.

Comment: then do it copy paste the code for every #kat1-7. I will not provide the code for you. I gave you the hint. Sorry but I'm not your coding bitch

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot to improve, but you can start with replace the ids with class

```
<style type="text/css">
.kat1 {
    background-image:url(ikoniceKategorije/07.jpg);
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    float:left;
    }
.kat1:hover {
    background-image:url(ikoniceKategorije/07h.jpg);
    }

.kat2 {
    background-image:url(ikoniceKategorije/06.jpg);
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    float:left;
    }
.kat2:hover {
    background-image:url(ikoniceKategorije/06h.jpg);
    }

.kat3 {
    background-image:url(ikoniceKategorije/05.jpg);
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    float:left;
    }
.kat3:hover {
    background-image:url(ikoniceKategorije/05h.jpg);
    }

.kat4 {
    background-image:url(ikoniceKategorije/04.jpg);
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    float:left;
    }
.kat4:hover {
    background-image:url(ikoniceKategorije/04h.jpg);
    }
.kat5 {
    background-image:url(ikoniceKategorije/03.jpg);
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    float:left;
    }
.kat5:hover {
    background-image:url(ikoniceKategorije/03h.jpg);
    }

.kat6 {
    background-image:url(ikoniceKategorije/02.jpg);
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    float:left;
    }
.kat6:hover {
    background-image:url(ikoniceKategorije/02h.jpg);
    }

.kat7 {
    background-image:url(ikoniceKategorije/01.jpg);
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    float:left;
    }
.kat7:hover {
    background-image:url(ikoniceKategorije/01h.jpg);
    }
.foo{
    background-image:url(somePcitureThatYouWant.jpg); <===
}   
#div {
    width:220px;
    height:30px;
    overflow:hidden;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="div">
        <div class="kat1 changing"></div> 
        <div class="kat2 changing"></div>
        <div class="kat3 changing"></div>
        <div class="kat4 changing"></div>
        <div class="kat5 changing"></div>
        <div class="kat6 changing"></div>
        <div class="kat7 changing"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Jquery Code:**

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.changing').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('foo').removeClass();
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: where I need to place jquery code... sorry for this but I'm beginer to this html-css-js

Comment: @MikiCloud. Inside `<script>` tag.

Comment: @MikiCloud. Do you have definitions for 'foo' and bar classes? I think some basic javascript and jquery could really help you.

Comment: Yes, but please tell me where I need to place that definitions?

Comment: @MikiCloud. Inside the `<style>`-css definitions.

Comment: I place you jquery code into <head> section... but what I need exactly write into style ???

Comment: @MikiCloud. The style you want for the div when it's clicked.

Comment: I know that but I need sintax, and please upadate your answer - to check your answer as correct

Comment: @MikiCloud. I added that class definition. I can't teach HTML, JavaScript CSS and jQuery inside the comments...

Comment: it's not what I need but THANKS A LOT!

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript functions for the divs to respond to `onmousedown` and `onmouseup` events, to change the background style or alternately the class attribute of the div back and forth. Alternately you can use `onclick`, in which case another click is required to change back.

The below code contains both solutions: kat1 has `onmousedown` and `onmouseup`, kat2 has `onclick`.

And by the way, since `width`, `height` and `float` are common attributes to all categories, they should need only one definition in the style.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
#div {
    width:220px;
    height:30px;
    overflow:hidden;
    }

#div div {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    float:left;
    }

.kat1, .kat1_active {
    background-image:url(/ikoniceKategorije/07.jpg);
    }
.kat1:hover {
    background-image:url(/ikoniceKategorije/07h.jpg);
    }

.kat2 {
    background-image:url(/ikoniceKategorije/06.jpg);
    }
.kat2_active {
    background-image:url(/ikoniceKategorije/06h.jpg);
    }

.kat3 {
    background-image:url(/ikoniceKategorije/05.jpg);
    }
.kat3:hover {
    background-image:url(/ikoniceKategorije/05h.jpg);
    }

.kat4 {
    background-image:url(/ikoniceKategorije/04.jpg);
    }
.kat4:hover {
    background-image:url(/ikoniceKategorije/04h.jpg);
    }

.kat5 {
    background-image:url(/ikoniceKategorije/03.jpg);
    }
.kat5:hover {
    background-image:url(/ikoniceKategorije/03h.jpg);
    }

.kat6 {
    background-image:url(/ikoniceKategorije/02.jpg);
    }
.kat6:hover {
    background-image:url(/ikoniceKategorije/02h.jpg);
    }

.kat7 {
    background-image:url(/ikoniceKategorije/01.jpg);
    }
.kat7:hover {
    background-image:url(/ikoniceKategorije/01h.jpg);
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle(element) {
    var index = element.className.indexOf('_active');
    if (index == -1) {
        element.className += '_active';
    } else {
        element.className = element.className.substring(0, index);
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="div">
        <div class="kat1" onmousedown="this.className='kat1_active'" onmouseup="this.className='kat1'"></div>
        <div class="kat2" onclick="toggle(this)"></div>
        <div class="kat3"></div>
        <div class="kat4"></div>
        <div class="kat5"></div>
        <div class="kat6"></div>
        <div class="kat7"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```